# I am trying to fit an GARCH(p,q) model to FX volatility. Should I be interested in the t-value of GARCH parameters?

Tags: volatility, garch

So what I am trying to do is to model the volatility for different currencies by fitting a GARCH(p, q) model. I am selecting the values of (p, q) by iteratively going through p & q such that max(p, q) = 5. After going through the 24 different combinations of p & q (excluding where p = q = 0), I select the model which has the lowest Akaike Information Criterion. I am doing all this in R using the rugarch package.

For the "best" model selected for some currencies, I observed that the t-value is extremely low. I have observed t-value of omega in a GARCH(1, 1) model as low as 0.09. My question is that can I still use the model if the GARCH parameters are statistically insignificant? Or am I mistaken and the usual "statistical significance of model parameters" which I learned for linear regression doesn't apply for GARCH type models.

I am a newbie to this field but I do not mind trying to learn from the start so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post became kind of lengthy, so if you're only interested in what you should do, just skip to the summary in the end. However, I think most of the confusion about these tests in general stems from a lack of knowledge about what one is actually doing, when applying the test.

First, let's take a look at *what* we are testing. As you said, you want to see, whether the GARCH parameters are "significant", according to the test, in order to choose a lag order.

**Generally**, for a parameter estimate $\hat\beta$, we want to test the null hypothesis $\mathcal{H}_0:\hat\beta=\beta_0$ against the alternative $\hat\beta\ne\beta_0$. As we want to see, whether our parameters are "significantly different from zero", we apply the test with $\beta_0=0$. Then, the **t-statistic** is given by
    \begin{align}\label{52}
 t_{\hat\beta}=\frac{\hat\beta-\beta_0}{\sigma_{\hat\beta}}=\frac{\hat\beta}{\sigma_{\hat\beta}},
 \end{align}
    where $\sigma_{\hat\beta}$ denotes the standard error of our estimate $\hat\beta$, i.e. the standard deviation of its sampling distribution.

Now, one of the main assumptions of the test comes into play, namely that the estimator is normally distributed. As you use the `rugarch` package, estimation is done by MLE. Thus, one can note that the asymptotic distribution of $\hat\beta$ is $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_{\hat\beta}^2)$ under the null hypothesis and some regularity conditions. 
Hence, in this case the t-statistic is asymptotically standard normally distributed. Considering that the standard normal distribution is symmetric, we can approximate the p-value by
      \begin{align}\label{53}
   p=2\cdot(1-\Phi(|t_{\hat\beta}|)),
   \end{align}
    with $\Phi(\cdot)$ denoting the standard normal cumulative distribution function.

**Numerically**, to use this test, we firstly have to compute the standard error $\sigma_{\hat\beta}$. This can be (and usually is) done for every estimated parameter at once, by approximating the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ with the inverse observed information matrix ${\mathcal I}^{-1}$. The latter is given by the negative hessian of the likelihood $-\hat{\mathbf{H}}$, or the hessian of the negative likelihood, evaluated at the maximum likelihood estimate. Altogether, this means
    \begin{align}\label{54}
 \Sigma\approx\mathcal{I}^{-1}=(-\hat{\mathbf{H}})^{-1},
 \end{align}
    which yields the standard errors for every parameter estimate, by calculating 
    \begin{align}\label{55}
 \sqrt{\text{diag}\left((-\hat{\mathbf{H}})^{-1}\right)}.
 \end{align}

Now, let's look into some of the possible issues one might encounter:

- The estimator could be non-normally distributed. In your case, as you're using MLE, the asymptotic gaussian distribution could be inaccurate for small sample sizes.
- The inversion of the hessian may prove to be difficult and require high numerical precision, specifically for highly (in)significant parameters.
- It should be kept in mind that, inherently, statistical tests don't give you the probability that the null hypothesis is true, but the probability of observing the data, *given that the null hypothesis is true*.

**In summary**, what I wanted to say is: The test certainly has its issues and shouldn't be used as the only deciding factor. However, it can provide some insight into the impact that a parameter has on a model's estimates.
Thus, when deciding the lag order of models, one should always additionally consult other model selection measures, like e.g. information criteria (AIC/BIC). The t-values can be used as pointers, which parameters could be omitted for a potentially better fit.